# Create an Android Emoji App

Tags: android, android-studio, emoji

I want to create and app with emoji for Android.
I have the drawable resources, but where I have to put the resource or how can I get the access to the user to use when he is writing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the access to the user to use when he is writing"?

Comment: My app has the Emoji pack, how can the user use in your chats n whatsapp or facebook or twitter?

Comment: So you want to spoof standard emoji with your emoji for chatting apps?

Comment: Yes, like this app -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kkkeyboard.emoji.keyboard.theme.RainbowLove

Comment: That's an Android keyboard "app" not a generic Android app.

Comment: @FishStix that is my question, is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These libraries can help you to make your app.

You can check this out

**1.[emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)**

-A library to show emoji in TextView, EditText (like WhatsApp) for Android

gradle

```
compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:<latest-version>'
```

**2.[XhsEmoticonsKeyboard](https://github.com/w446108264/XhsEmoticonsKeyboard)**

-android emoticonsKeyboard support emoji and user-defined emoticon. easy to integrated into your project

gradle

```
compile 'com.github.w446108264:XhsEmoticonsKeyboard:2.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

As emoticons are mipmaps and do not need to change size depending on the screen size, you should put resources in the main mipmaps folder, so not mipmaps-hdpi or any other qualifier.

To respond to user writing, you must use **TextWatcher** on EditText views.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

The *onTextChanged* handler allows you to react to any text entries on runtime.

When you detect symbols like ':)' you can then modify them to ☺

Use HTML functions to display and send images trought messages :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: Do you know a github example?

Comment: look at skydroid's answer :)

Comment: But if i want to use in whatsapp chat, what do i need?